# Xen: resizing underlying iSCSI SAN volume

Tags: xen, storage-area-network

I have a SAN volume that provides the storage for 3 machines running Xen 6.2. The volume is down to about 10% free but there is more available unallocated.

The SAN (Equallogic) supports volume resizing but pops up some warnings before it lets you proceed:

1. "Some OS don't support volumes > 2 Tb"
2. "Its recommended to take a snapshot before you resize"

I don't have space to store a 2Tb snapshot but #1 concerns me a tad.

Has anyone done this (resize) before? How did it go? From what I've read it shouldn't be a big deal but it would mess up my day to kill dozens of machines (as VMs) in one swift motion.

---

EDIT: Just read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/526599/san-is-it-better-to-have-separate-luns-for-operating-system-and-data-of-virtual?rq=1). A better option?

FWIW: afterwards I was going to follow [these](http://labs.wrprojects.com/expanding-a-multipath-iscsi-lun-in-a-xenserver-6-pool-without-downtime/) directions.